# Is there a Birkhoff-like theorem for axially symmetric gravity fields?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, symmetry, metric-tensor

As we know, to derive the Schwarzschild solution in GR we want to determine the unknown functions $a,b$ (sometimes $c$) of
$$(ds)^2 = a(r,t)\;dt^2 - b(r,t)\; dr^2 - r^2d\Omega^2 $$
or
$$ (ds)^2 = a(r,t)\;dt^2 + 2b(r,t)\;drdt - c(r,t)\; dr^2 - r^2d\Omega^2  $$
where $d\Omega^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta \; d\phi^2 \; $ is the usual line element of the 2-sphere. When applied to the empty space field equations where $G_{ab} \equiv 0$, Birkhoff's theorem says any static, spherically symmetric solution to the vacuum equations of general relativity is necessarily the Schwarzschild solution up to a coordinate transformation. That basically wraps up looking for exterior spherically symmetric solutions in GR. The next logical step is then to look for interior solutions which is a whole different ball game.

I'm interested in considering axially symmetric spacetimes in GR. The usual approach is to look at [Weyl metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_metrics) (as mentioned in the comments below) and go for broke.

What I am confused about is trying to consider one of the following line element
$$ (ds)^2 = a(r,\theta)\;dt^2 + 2b(r,\theta)\;drdt - c(r,\theta)\; dr^2 - r^2d\Omega^2. $$

The above line element is axially symmetric also correct? In terms of polar spherical coordinates it is symmetric about the polar angle coordinate.

In terms of a spacetime that models a non-spherically symmetric body for e.g. a planet, I would have thought that this line element is more suitable than the general Weyl metric. However, I have never seen a method beginning with the above line element.

**Question**
Is the Weyl solution to axially symmetric gravitational fields as Schwarzschild solutions are to spherically symmetric gravitational fields?
 In other words, is there a Birkhoff-type theorem for axially symmetric solutions to the field equations of GR?

Comment: See Weyl metrics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_metrics

Comment: @Void: aren't the Weyl metrics are axisymmetric?

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, it is true that Weyl metrics address only to the "angular dependency" (in $\theta$) but not specifically the $\phi$-dependency as proposed here.

Comment: That was just an example, the dependency ins't set in stone for e.g. it could be $(r,\theta)$,$(r,\phi)$ or any variation of the coordinates. What I'm interested in is stepping away from the standard Schwarzschild solution and RN solution and that pesky Birkhoff's theorem!

Answer (score 1):

Many exact solutions to EFE (Einistein's field equations) with varying degrees of symmetry have been found.

This Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_solutions_in_general_relativity) and references therein are excellent introduction to this field.

As a book reference, the standard one is:
H. Stephani, D. Kramer, M. MacCallum, C. Hoenselaers, E. Herlt, “Exact Solutions of Einstein’s Field Equations: 2nd Edition”, (2003), Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Okay, I'll be sure to check them out but more specifically to what I asked have you any experience with solutions to the EFE of this type?